# Adding an Electrical Outlet when original is in conduit (what do I do with the ground?)

Tags: receptacle

My home was built in 2015 and all of the electrical wiring is in conduit and there are no ground wires.  I am looking to add another electrical outlet in our bedroom for a wall mounted TV.  I used the last receptacle in the series and have wired up both outlets already.  What do I do with the ground wire that I brought into the box with the existing outlet that I am tapping off of?

Comment: This is metal conduit we're talking about, right?

Comment: Also, are you in the Chicago area, or another area where local electrical code amendments require the use of conduit?

Comment: Yes, it is metal conduit and no, local code does not require conduit, it was a preference of the builder.

Comment: The metal conduit system is the ground system.  Connect your ground wire to the last box with a 10-32 green ground screw into a pretapped hole in that last box.

Answer (score 2):

It's apparent the contractor is using the conduit system as a ground. You didn't mention what you are using for the extension but I am assuming it's some sort of approved cable. You can attach the ground to the box the existing receptacle is in. You will find a threaded 10/32 hole in the back of the box. You can purchase a ground screw at just about any hardware store.

I must caution you that if you are in a municipality that only allows conduit systems in houses you should install expansion's in like systems.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Ground screw hole in the back of metal electrical boxes is 10/32.

Comment: I was going to make the same comment +

Comment: do not forget, if the expansion is not up to local standards, and something happens that results in an insurance claim, the insurance may be null and void because of the expansion

Comment: I'm in the same situation. I can add conduit through the wall from the basement, but is there some sort of retrofit box like they make for ceiling fans that you twist and will brace and tighten up against the studs? Trying to avoid cutting up the drywall too much in order to screw in and anchor the box to a stud.